# How to use add action to call a wordpress function and still get a return value?

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets say I have a random function with a return value:

```
function someFunction() { 
   return 1234;
}
```

And now I wanna call that function using add_action and set a variable to the return value of the function:

```
$somevar = add_action('plugins_loaded', 'someFunction');
```

However add_action always returns true, so the value of $somevar ends up being true instead of the return value. Is there a way to set the variable to the return value?

I cant really get around using add_action.

Comment: Actions differ from filters as they don't care about propergating a response. your `someFunction` should do something like echo html or do some programatic work. What are you expecting to be the consumer your return response? the `plugins_loaded` is called at a specific point in the wordpress loading cycle, `add_action()` returns true because your callback was registered for future execution,

Comment: @Scuzzy Im trying to get the current user through 
`$user = add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wp_get_current_user' );`

Comment: just use `$user = wp_get_current_user();` ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/

Comment: @Scuzzy Then then `wp_get_current_user`  is called before the plugins are loaded and it doesnt work.

Comment: Wordpress hasn't bootstrapped the user account yet, You need to re-engineer your code to work with the user account after its been loaded. Generally around the `init` hook, the earliest is `set_current_user` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_current_user/

Answer (score 0):

According to the WordPress documentation `add_action()` always returns `true` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

This function is simply used to register a callback function to execute at the respecitve execution point during the wordrpess life cycle. Nothing more. see also https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

the `plugins_loaded` action is saying "once all the wordrpess plugins have loaded, execute these additional tasks" before moving onto the rest of the wordpress code.

```
/**
 * Fires once activated plugins have loaded.
 *
 * Pluggable functions are also available at this point in the loading order.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 */
do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );
```